# Welcome aboard page in Rails 4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Usually deleting the public/index.html in my Rails app works. 
However, I recently updated Rails,I'm using version 4.0 now, and the public/index.html no longer exist. What should I do to get rid of the "Welcome Aboard" page in Rails 4.0?

Comment: you don't have to get rid of it anymore. (that was rails 3 :). Now i'ts replaced as soon you set the root path as described in your config/routes.rb file.

Comment: This is also only visible in development environment: `if Rails.env.development?
          app.routes.append do
            get '/rails/info/properties' => "rails/info#properties"
            get '/rails/info/routes'     => "rails/info#routes"
            get '/rails/info'            => "rails/info#index"
            get '/'                      => "rails/welcome#index"
          end`    https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the root route in `config/routes.rb`. For example, to default to the `index` action in your `welcome` controller:

```
root "welcome#index"
```

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#setting-the-application-home-page